# In which year do we get the 12%/18%/21% of tax reduction when investing in an SCPI Pinel?

Tags: taxes, france, reit

[SCPI Pinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Real_estate_investment_trust&oldid=800066665#France) is a type of French REIT.

I read on http://www.boursorama.com/actualites/les-avantages-des-scpi-pinel-0524a8065c484c7099578a81ced7d67d ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20171021195959/http://www.boursorama.com/actualites/les-avantages-des-scpi-pinel-0524a8065c484c7099578a81ced7d67d))

> Une fiscalité avantageuse:
>
> En souscrivant des parts de SCPI Pinel,
> l'associé profite d'une réduction d'impôt sur le revenu dès l'année de
> souscription. Nul besoin pour lui d'attendre la livraison des
> immeubles.
>
> L'avantage fiscal pour les associés de SCPI est calculé de la même
> manière que pour les particuliers qui achètent un logement neuf en
> direct. Il porte sur la totalité du montant de l'investissement et non
> plus comme dans la loi Duflot sur 95 %.
>
> Selon la durée de détention des parts, la réduction d'impôt varie :
>
> - Réduction de 12 % du montant investi dans une SCPI sur 6 ans limité à 36 000 €
> - Réduction de 18 % du montant investi dans une SCPI sur 9 ans, limité à 54 000 €
> - Réduction de 21 % du montant investi dans une SCPI sur 12 ans, limité à 63 000 €.

Which Google [translates](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Une%20fiscalit%C3%A9%20avantageuse%0A%0AEn%20souscrivant%20des%20parts%20de%20SCPI%20Pinel%2C%20l%27associ%C3%A9%20profite%20d%27une%20r%C3%A9duction%20d%27imp%C3%B4t%20sur%20le%20revenu%20d%C3%A8s%20l%27ann%C3%A9e%20de%20souscription.%20Nul%20besoin%20pour%20lui%20d%27attendre%20la%20livraison%20des%20immeubles.%0A%0AL%27avantage%20fiscal%20pour%20les%20associ%C3%A9s%20de%20SCPI%20est%20calcul%C3%A9%20de%20la%20m%C3%AAme%20mani%C3%A8re%20que%20pour%20les%20particuliers%20qui%20ach%C3%A8tent%20un%20logement%20neuf%20en%20direct.%20Il%20porte%20sur%20la%20totalit%C3%A9%20du%20montant%20de%20l%27investissement%20et%20non%20plus%20comme%20dans%20la%20loi%20Duflot%20sur%2095%20%25.%0A%0ASelon%20la%20dur%C3%A9e%20de%20d%C3%A9tention%20des%20parts%2C%20la%20r%C3%A9duction%20d%27imp%C3%B4t%20varie%20%3A%0A%0A-%20R%C3%A9duction%20de%2012%20%25%20du%20montant%20investi%20dans%20une%20SCPI%20sur%206%20ans%20limit%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%2036%20000%20%E2%82%AC%20%0A%0A-%20R%C3%A9duction%20de%2018%20%25%20du%20montant%20investi%20dans%20une%20SCPI%20sur%209%20ans%2C%20limit%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%2054%20000%20%E2%82%AC%20%0A%0A-%20R%C3%A9duction%20de%2021%20%25%20du%20montant%20investi%20dans%20une%20SCPI%20sur%2012%20ans%2C%20limit%C3%A9%20%C3%A0%2063%20000%20%E2%82%AC.) as:

> An advantageous tax system
>
> By subscribing shares in Pinel SCPI, the partner benefits from an
> income tax reduction as of the subscription year. No need for him to
> wait for the delivery of the buildings.
>
> The tax benefit for SCPI's partners is calculated in the same way as
> for individuals who buy a new home directly. It covers the entire
> amount of the investment and no longer as in the law Duflot on 95%.
>
> Depending on the holding period of the units, the tax reduction
> varies:
>
> - Reduction of 12% of the amount invested in a SCPI over 6 years limited to € 36,000
> - Reduction of 18% of the amount invested in a SCPI over 9 years, limited to € 54,000
> - 21% reduction in the amount invested in a 12-year SCPI limited to € 63,000.

In which yet do we get the 12%/18%/21% of tax reduction when investing in an SCPI Pinel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.capital.fr/immobilier/les-scpi-fiscales-une-solution-pour-baisser-ses-impots-et-bloquer-son-epargne-1114747  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022203923/https://www.capital.fr/immobilier/les-scpi-fiscales-une-solution-pour-baisser-ses-impots-et-bloquer-son-epargne-1114747)):

> Les SCPI Pinel permettent à l’investisseur de bénéficier d’une réduction d’impôt échelonnée en fonction de la durée de détention. Pour un engagement de conservation des parts de SCPI pendant 9 ou 12 ans, la réduction d’impôt représentera 18%, respectivement 21%, du montant total de la souscription. **La réduction d’impôt sera alors répartie linéairement sur le nombre d’années** mais attention elle rentre dans le plafond global des niches fiscales, ce qui n’est pas le cas des autres SCPI fiscales spécialisées, elles, dans la rénovation d’immeubles.

Which Google [translates](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Les%20SCPI%20Pinel%20permettent%20%C3%A0%20l%E2%80%99investisseur%20de%20b%C3%A9n%C3%A9ficier%20d%E2%80%99une%20r%C3%A9duction%20d%E2%80%99imp%C3%B4t%20%C3%A9chelonn%C3%A9e%20en%20fonction%20de%20la%20dur%C3%A9e%20de%20d%C3%A9tention.%20Pour%20un%20engagement%20de%20conservation%20des%20parts%20de%20SCPI%20pendant%209%20ou%2012%20ans%2C%20la%20r%C3%A9duction%20d%E2%80%99imp%C3%B4t%20repr%C3%A9sentera%2018%25%2C%20respectivement%2021%25%2C%20du%20montant%20total%20de%20la%20souscription.%20La%20r%C3%A9duction%20d%E2%80%99imp%C3%B4t%20sera%20alors%20r%C3%A9partie%20lin%C3%A9airement%20sur%20le%20nombre%20d%E2%80%99ann%C3%A9es%20mais%20attention%20elle%20rentre%20dans%20le%20plafond%20global%20des%20niches%20fiscales%2C%20ce%20qui%20n%E2%80%99est%20pas%20le%20cas%20des%20autres%20SCPI%20fiscales%20sp%C3%A9cialis%C3%A9es%2C%20elles%2C%20dans%20la%20r%C3%A9novation%20d%E2%80%99immeubles.) as:

> Pinel SCPIs allow the investor to benefit from a tax reduction spread over the duration of the holding. For a commitment to keep SCPI shares for 9 or 12 years, the tax reduction will represent 18%, or 21%, of the total amount of the subscription. **The tax reduction will then be spread linearly over the number of years**, but beware it falls within the overall ceiling of tax loopholes, which is not the case for the other tax-focused REITs that are specialized in the renovation of buildings.